# Parsing a JSON object with invalid key values using Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've been using Spring boot for a while now so I can say that I am pretty comfortable with using it.

However there is one problem that I can never solve. 
When I want my Spring boot server to consume a JSON object coming from the front end I usually use @RequestBody like this:
If the JSON object looks like this:

```
{"name":"Jason"}
```

I would create a POJO like this:

```
public class User{
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }


    public String getName(){
        return this.name
    }
}
```

And then in my main controller i would simply use @RequestBody like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    //code here
}
```

And this would work because the key "name" in the JSON object matches the attribute "name" of the Java User object.

However, in my current project there I have to consume a JSON objects with keys like {" # Name ":"Jason"}

In this case I can not create a POJO object with an attribute called # Name because obviously an object's attribute cannot start with # and cannot have spaces.

When faced with problems like this I usually do

```
@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> map
```

and then

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setName(map.get(" # Name"));
```

However when you have a JSON object with 40+ keys this can become troublesome.

Is there an easier way to parse JSON objects with keys that would appear invalid in Java like this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try annotating your `name` member with `@JsonProperty`.

```
@JsonProperty(" # name")
private String name;
```

This will allow the deserialiser to match the key in your JSON payload with your POJO member.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I didn't come to Stack Overflow earlier -_- .. This would of saved me ages of time wasted on working with a hashmap! Thanks a lot darrengorman ! Exactly what I was looking for! Works like magic!